# Android Emulator running into loading problems

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, gpu, android-virtual-device

Up until 2 days ago, everything has been working fine and perfect. I was using the Nexus 5x and 4 emulators with no issues apart from a few crashes on the 5x due to virtual memory.
Now everytime I try to load any of my emulators, I am greeted with a "GPU driver issue" error box
[image] 
and the emulator I'm working on loads but is very laggy and virtual unusable and the UI of the app I'm testing keeps bugging out. 
 I tried updating my driver, in fact this is the error message I got after updating to try and resolve the problem which was the same as before updating but different version number.
I've also tried using the Software GLES 2.0 setting instead of Hardware GLES 2.0 or Automatic under Graphics in the emulator settings but still run into the same error. 
 I've tried completely removing Android studio and all associated files and reinstalling but still the same issue.
This is very frustrating as I do not have a working device to test and so emulation is my only option at the moment, and just two days everything was fine and all of a sudden this error keeps popping up.
Any advice is appreciated.
My IDE is Android Studio 2.3, Windows 8.1, 8GB RAM. I've tried using the Nexus 5x, Nexus 4, Pixel XL, Nexus 6P emulators, but same error.

Comment: Seeing the same now: on ubuntu 17.04 - worked nice before - now an error like this and kind of unusable

Comment: thanks! just changed to these settings and restarted the device - still slower than before

Comment: @ligi Hmm. When you said restart, did you mean power on/off or did you close the emulator completely and restart from the AVD manager? If the latter, then I'm not sure what the issue is. Like I said, I still got the pop up message, it's just back to the usual speed I once had. You said it was fine before, so I guess you have the usual emulator settings for smooth use. Try deleting the emulator and creating a new one with the default settings, and maybe using 512MB for VM instead of the default 256MB. Apart from that, hopefully someone comes along with an actual solution the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I believe I have found a solution.

After running the Android Emulator, then heading to the overflow menu options in the side bar:

[image]

Under settings I changed my render options to the following:

[image]

This seemed to solve my issue as far as usability goes. Now the emulator is fast enough to use however I still get the pop up message as stated in the question. I'll just check "Never show this again" for now.